# 'Then' in a custom JavaScript Promise created from scratch is executed before promise resolves. What is the reason?

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to create a simple custom promise from scratch.

For some reason, `then` is being executed before the `onResolve function` is called.
Because of this, the `response` variable is an empty string.
Where am I going wrong here?

Index.js

```
import CustomPromise from "./customPromise";
const makeApiCall = () => {
  return new CustomPromise((success, failure) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let apiResponse = { statusCode: 200, response: "hello" };
      if (apiResponse.statusCode == 200) {
        success(apiResponse);
      } else {
        failure(apiResponse);
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
};
makeApiCall().then(response => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

CustomPromise.js

```
export default class CustomPromise {
  constructor(executorFunc) {
    this.onResolve = this.onResolve.bind(this);
    this.onReject = this.onReject.bind(this);
    this.response = "";
    executorFunc(this.onResolve, this.onReject);
  }
  then(input) {
    input(this.response);
  }
  onResolve(response) {
    this.response = response;
  }

  onReject(input) {
    input();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `CustomPromise.then` you can see that you are just taking the continuation `input` and calling it immediately regardless of the state of the promise. I think what you'd want to do is to create a `task queue` and on resolve, you would go ahead and execute it.

You are missing a few key things as well.

1. First you need to maintain a `state` inside the promise so that you know when a promise has been `settled`. This makes it so that you cant resolve/reject the promise multiple times.
2. Your `reject` function probably shouldn't just be executing the input. You typically pass a `reason` into the rejection which will then execute all `catch` tasks.
3. No chaining support. Not sure that was even your goal.

```js
const functionOrNoop = (fn) => {
  let result = () => {};

  if (typeof fn === "function") {
    result = fn;
  }

  return result;
};

class CustomPromise {
  constructor(executor) {
    this.queue = [];
    this.state = "pending";
    this.value = null;
    this.reason = null;

    executor(this.onResolve, this.onReject);
  }

  static reject(reason) {
    return new CustomPromise((_, reject) => reject(reason));
  }

  static resolve(value) {
    return new CustomPromise((resolve) => resolve(value));
  }

  then(fn) {
    return new CustomPromise((resolve, reject) => {
      const resolved = (value) => {
        try {
          resolve(fn(value))
        } catch (e) {
          reject(e);
        }
      };

      this.enqueue({
        resolved,
        rejected: reject
      });
    });
  }

  catch (fn) {
    return new CustomPromise((resolve, reject) => {
      const rejected = (reason) => {
        try {
          resolve(fn(reason))
        } catch (e) {
          reject(e);
        }
      };

      this.enqueue({
        rejected
      });
    });
  }

  onResolve = (value) => {
    if (this.state === "pending") {
      this.state = "resolved";
      this.value = value;
      this.finalize();
    }
  }

  onReject = (reason) => {
    if (this.state === "pending") {
      this.state = "rejected";
      this.reason = reason;
      this.finalize();
    }
  };

  enqueue(task) {
    if (this.state === "pending") {
      this.queue.push(task);
    } else {
      this.eval(task);
    }
  }

  eval(task) {
    if (this.state === "resolved") {
      functionOrNoop(task.resolved)(this.value);
    } else if (this.state === "rejected") {
      functionOrNoop(task.rejected)(this.reason);
    }
  }

  finalize() {
    this.queue.forEach((task) => this.eval(task));
    this.queue = [];
  }
}

const p = CustomPromise.resolve("hello")

p
  .then((value) => value.toUpperCase())
  .then((value) => `J${value.slice(1)}`)
  .then((value) => console.log(value))

p.then((value) => console.log(value));

p
  .then(() => {
    throw new Error(":(")
  })
  .catch((e) => console.log(e.message))
  .then(() => {
    throw new Error(":)")
  })
  .then(() => console.log("SHOULD NOT CALL!"))
  .catch((e) => console.log(e.message));
```

This is meant to serve as an example(so expect bugs) but it encapsulates some of the things I mentioned above. Promises are really complex and you are missing things like 'microtasking' and tens of thousands of hours to testing, development, and vetting.